# OOP principle of "coding to an interface"?

Tags: java, arraylist

I read somewhere that we should instantiate an ArrayList polymorphically like this:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

but if i use

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
```

this approach i can see more number of methods when i type `myList.(ctrl+space)`

Please guide me about the differences (pros and cons) between them

Comment: I edited the question to ask about the differences instead of which is the preferred method (making the question more fit to StackOverflow)

Answer (score 4):

Typically the reason you code to an interface is so that you can swap out the concrete class you're using later on if that makes sense. For instance, if you needed to swap `ArrayList` for `LinkedList` because you discovered memory fragmentation/reallocation issues. You'd just have to change the line constructing the object, and not your other code, because you coded to the `List` interface, and both of those concrete classes implement `List`.

If you *need* to use one of the `ArrayList` methods that isn't on the `List` interface, then it's fine to change the declaration and use that method. You just have to be aware, then, that you're coupling your code tightly to `ArrayList`, a specific concrete class, rather than to `List`, an interface implemented by a wide range of classes.

Your default position should be to code to the interface, as that gives you maximum flexibility / minimum coupling. But that doesn't mean you don't use the class directly when you need to, just that you start out being as flexible as possible.

Comment: @LaiVung: Pathetic, isn't it? I need a life. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the approach you propose you will be tight to a particluar implementation of the container, which is not good in many situations. If you need to use methods that are only present in `ArrayList` you have two options - either declare `myList` as `ArrayList`, or downcast `myList` whenever you need a method only found in `ArrayList`.

Comment: can you please explain this in little brief.It will help me to understand better,I am new to java.